# How to sort the array based on index in PDO

Tags: php, arrays

I am using this code to fetch the desired result from the database

```
$status = 'passed';
$allTest = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(testRunID),platform FROM tooldata WHERE status = :status GROUP BY platform' );
$allTest->execute(array(':status' => $status));

while($row = $allTest->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    { 
    foreach($row as $key) 
        {
            $totalTest[] = $key;

        } 
    }

print_r($totalTest);
```

the output of **print_r($totalTest)** is like **[output]**(http://pastebin.com/QW46ieYy). Now I want to sort this array based on the platform, which is the odd index. How this can be done ?

Also after sorting the array, I just want the even index value is a separate array

Comment: Can you not `ORDER BY` the query instead?

Comment: @Digzol - No because values are alphanumeric.

Comment: And so what? what's wrong with sorting alphanumeric values?

Comment: on the other hand, if you think they are unsortable, how they are supposed to be sorted in PHP?

Answer (score -1):

```
$status = 'passed';
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(testRunID),platform FROM tooldata WHERE status = ? GROUP BY platform';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($status));
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ROW))
{ 
    $totalTest[$row[1]] = $row[0]; // sorted by platform which is key
}
$another = $totalTest;
asort($another); // sorted by count
```

Comment: and this is throwing error -  **Undefined class constant 'FETCH_ROW'**

Comment: well, it's a typo, I am sure you're able to fix it yourself